# Possible SEO repercussions of using no-transform headers?

Tags: seo, google-search

Google renders weblight versions of few of our pages intermittently, and that kills all interactivity. Optimizing the pages to the fullest is ofcourse a method to lessen weblight transformation, we want to avoid it completely. 
As mentioned in the [documentation](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6211428?hl=en), we intend to send `no-transform` response header in our pages to signal Google to not generate a weblight version of the pages.

> Opting out of Web Light 
>   If you do not want your pages to be
>   transcoded, set the HTTP header "Cache-Control: no-transform" in your
>   page response. If Googlebot sees this header, your page will not be
>   transcoded.

My question is that is there any possible SEO effect we shall be cautious about due to this ?

Answer (score 1):

I have sites that also opt out of Google Weblight as the cart doesn't function so nothing can be purchased.

I have seen no adverse effect since we added the "Cache-Control: no-transform" header, no drop in mobile traffic, CR, or anything else.

Google mention that your site may be marked as slow in the mobile SERPS, but I have only seen this when using a really slow mobile connection, think edge speed.

I also doubt many people pay attention to this warning anyway.

Comment: John Mueller from Google just tweeted: https://www.seroundtable.com/cache-control-headers-google-seo-25898.html

Comment: I had also confirmed the specific weblight case from John : https://twitter.com/dhruvpathak/status/1004652940622204929